# Measure of inequality in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Supposed I have an object

```
{0: Array(2), 1: Array(11), 2: Array(3), 3: Array(7), 4: Array(5), 5: Array(4)}
```

and I want to measure how equally or unequally the items are distributed in each item of this object — e.g. highly unequal would be if all the 32 items were in the array 0, while highly equal would be if each array had approximately the same number of items.

Is there a Javascript function or library that would calculate this?

Comment: Not sure about a built in function or library, but you can, for instance, find the range (longest minus shortest) through `v = Object.values(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE).map(n=>n.length); console.log(Math.max(...v) - Math.min(...v))`. If it's near zero, it's perfectly distributed, if the highest and lowest value are far apart, then it's not very well distributed. The thing is, "evenly distributed" is a very broad term, and we'd be able to help you better if you a) described exactly what you mean by "evenly distributed" and b) showed what research you've already done that's failed. :)

Comment: Looks like you need to calculate the [**variance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of the lengths of your arrays.

Comment: Method 2: Calculating Variance of a Population from [**this wikihow**](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Variance) fits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

measuring the % of deviation or how unequally the data is distributed
making a graph like representation of the above problem

finding the total sum of all the elements of the array which is 32 items

counting all the array as one element which are 6 in total

find the average value for the given graph the closer the line is to the graph the more evenly all the items are distributed mean would be around 5.4

for all 6 elements do Σ (| average - (max or min value) | / average ) for all elements

```
{0: Array(2), 1: Array(11), 2: Array(3), 3: Array(7), 4: Array(5), 5: Array(4)}
```

(5.4 - 2 / 5.4) + (11 - 5.4 / 5.4) +  (5.4 - 3 / 5.4) + (7 - 5.4 / 5.4) + (5.4 - 5/5.4) + (5.4 - 4 / 5.4) = answer

convert this answer into %

answer * 100 / (no of array elments) == unequally distributed %

100 - unequally distributed  = you know the math!

Comment: — thank you, in fact those array objects are the communities in a network graph I'm visualizing so I want to measure how evenly the nodes are distributed in the graph. do you know any other measures that are used in graph analysis for a similar purpose?